# Load button in aptoncd wont work

Tags: 11.10, apt, button

I am using aptoncd for backup the cache
but in ubuntu 11.10 the load button wont work
so i opened from terminal when i pressing load button terminal shows timeout error
how to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install HAL:

```
sudo apt-get install hal
```

Then open `aptoncd`, it will work.